# issue with python plot

Tags: python, curve

So with this code I need to plot an IV-curve exponentially decaying, but it is in wrong direction and needs to be mirrored/flipped. The x andy  values are not being plotted in the correct axes and needs to be switched. It would show the relation with current exponentially decreasing while given a voltage.I tried all sorts of debugging, but it kept showing an exponential growth or the same kind of decay.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
xdata=np.linspace(23,0)# voltage data
ydata=np.exp(xdata)# current data
plt.plot(ydata,xdata)
plt.title(r'IV-curve')
plt.xlabel('Voltage(V)')
plt.ylabel('Current(I)')
plt.show()
```

Here's what it looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/27Imw.jpg

Also, bear with me as this may seem like a trivial code, but I literally started coding for the first time last week, so I will get some bumps on the road :)

Comment: I just posted an answer. let me know if this is what you want

Comment: @sera I tried your code, but it says sort is not defined

Comment: I edited my code. Use ydata = np.sort(ydata)

Comment: did it work ? Let me know please when you try the new code

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the `ydata` that you use **are not correctly ordered**.

The solution is simple. **Reorder** the `ydata`.

**Do this:**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

xdata = np.linspace(23,0)# voltage data
ydata = np.exp(xdata)# current data
ydata = np.sort(ydata)

plt.plot(ydata,xdata)
plt.title(r'IV-curve')
plt.xlabel('Voltage(V)')
plt.ylabel('Current(I)')

plt.show()
```

---

**Result:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like maybe

```
plt.plot(ydata,xdata)
```

should be

```
plt.plot(xdata,ydata)
```

This will correct the axes.  But you still aren't going to get a decaying exponential.  Why?  Not because of the plotting but because of your data.  Your data is a growing exponential.  If you want decay use something like

```
ydata=np.exp(-xdata)
```

i.e. minus sign in front of `xdata`.